# Count occurrences of duplicate elements in tuples from Cartesian power

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set $A = \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$ and the $N^\text{th}$ Cartesian power of this set $B = A \times A \times \ldots \times A = A^N$. (This implies that $|B| = N^N$.)

For example, if $N=2$ then $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2) \}$.

I am interested in counting the number of numbers $k$ that are duplicated in each element of $B$ as a function of $N$, denoted $c(N,k)$.  For example, when $N=2$, $\,c(2, 0) = 2$, $\,c(2, 1) = 0$, and $\,c(2, 2) = 2$.

EDIT: Another example-- in the tuple $(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2)$, there are considered to be 6 elements that are duplicated elsewhere in the tuple.

For $k=0$, the count is simply the number of permutations of $A$, i.e. $c(N,0) = N!$

For $k=1$, $\,c(N,1)=0 \quad \forall N \in \mathbb Z^+$ because an number must occur at least twice in each tuple to be counted.

For $k=2$, I empirically determined (basically by guessing and checking versus an exhaustive search) that $c(N,2) = N! N(N-1)/2 = N! {N \choose 2} $.

For $k=3$, I empirically determined that $c(N,3) = N! {N \choose 3} / 2$.

However, for higher values of $k$ I am neither able to determine a general formula that works for general $N$ and $k$ nor have I been able to construct a formula from "first principles".

Is this a canonical problem that has already been solved, or is there any systematic way of computing these counts?

Comment: This question requires more precise formulation. How many duplicates are there in $(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)$? Perhaps you should be asking how many instances of each partition?

Comment: @ScottBurns In your example, the count would be 7. Added a similar example to the main post.